# Sharepoint 2010 email mailto or server side code

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a requirement in SharePoint 2010 where, on click of ribbon button I want to open Outlook with To, Subject and body pre-populated, I have tried with mailto but it has character limitation for the url due to which I can not send more than 2000 some characters, is there any way I can do this with server side code, or is there any workaround for mailto.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is method in SPUtility SendMail you can use for it. 
REF: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.sendemail?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sharepoint-server#overloads